# Using dot notation for instance methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, key-value-coding

I was looking at a piece of code today and notice that this particular coder use dot notation to access instance methods (these methods don't take values, they just return value).

For example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

}
-(double)add;
@end

@implementation MyClass
-(double)valueA {
    return 3.0;
}

-(double)valueB {
    return 7.0;
}

-(double)add {
    return self.valueA + self.valueB;
}    
@end
```

He did this through out his code and the compiler doesn't complain, but when I try it in my code like the example above I get the following error: "Request for member "valueA" in something not a structure or union". What am I missing, any idea?

Comment: Those are instance methods (declared with leading `-`), not class methods (which would be declared with leading `+`).

Comment: @Jeremy you are right, I just changed the wording to 'instance' instead of 'class' methods. He was using self.instanceMethod to access the value that that method return. I couldn't duplicate this in my code without the compiler complaining.

Comment: We can't tell you what you're missing until you show us what you're doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dot syntax is usually applied to declared properties but that’s not mandatory. Using `obj.valueA` and `obj.valueB` does work.

The error message you’re getting is probably due to the object not having explicit type `MyClass *`. For example, the following works:

```
MyClass *obj1 = [MyClass new];
NSLog(@"%f %f %f", obj1.valueA, obj1.valueB, [obj1 add]);
```

On the other hand:

```
MyClass *obj1 = [MyClass new];
NSLog(@"%f %f %f", obj1.valueA, obj1.valueB, [obj1 add]);

id obj2 = obj1;
NSLog(@"%f %f %f", obj2.valueA, obj2.valueB, [obj2 add]);
```

gives:

```
error: request for member ‘valueA’ in something not a structure or union
error: request for member ‘valueB’ in something not a structure or union
```

because `obj2` has type `id`, so the compiler doesn’t have enough information to know that `.valueA` and `.valueB` are actually the getter methods `-valueA` and `-valueB`. This can happen if you place objects of type `MyClass` in an `NSArray` and later retrieve them via `-objectAtIndex:`, since this method returns a generic object of type `id`.

To appease the compiler, you need to cast the object to `MyClass *` and only then use the dot syntax. You could accomplish this by:

```
MyClass *obj2 = obj1;
// or
MyClass *obj2 = [someArray objectAtIndex:someIndex];
// and then
obj2.valueA
```

or, if `obj2` is declared as `id`:

```
((MyClass *)obj2).valueA
```

or, if the object is returned by a method whose return type is `id`:

```
((MyClass *)[someArray objectAtIndex:someIndex]).valueA
```

Alternatively, you could simply get rid of the dot syntax altogether (my favourite):

```
[obj2 valueA]
[[someArray objectAtIndex:someIndex] valueA]
```

Comment: @Grady Not really because there’s no need to dereference pointers to Objective-C objects in the general case, and `valueA` and `valueB` are not structure members.

Comment: for me, and I know you are the master, but (*a).valueA is fine and a->valueA is fine, but not a.valueA.

Comment: @Grady `(*a).valueA` would be fine if `valueA` were a structure member (e.g. an ivar, potentially a public one), but it isn’t. It is a method instead.

Comment: @Grady, you're confusing C (and also used in C++) structures and pointer syntax with the addition of Objective-C property syntax.  As mentioned above, when you don't have the full type information about the object (pointer) `MyClass`, it only sees `id` so then fails with the `structure or union` wording that is familiar to `C` programmers (because it's not valid C at this point).  When the compiler knows the type, it can correctly parse the syntax as the property syntax it is meant to be.

Comment: I never realized you could use the property notation, without a formal declaration. +1

Comment: @Grady That’s because it’s dot notation, not property notation. ;-) You can use it without declared properties, although it’s not very common.

Comment: does it just end up calling valueForKey:?