# Should I be casting when returning id from an objective-c method or not?

Tags: objective-c

For the Objective-C gurus:

Suppose I have a simple method like so:

```
-(id)getValue{ return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:5.0]; }
```

Now, suppose within some other method I call the (id)getValue method like so:

```
NSNumber* myValue = [self getValue];
```

or what if I call it like this instead:

```
NSNumber* myValue = (NSNumber*)[self getValue];
```

The question is:  Obviously these lines are equivalent but one of them utilizes an explicit cast.  So what is the correct or best-practice way of doing this.  It seams to me the cast is unnecessary since when it is placed in the pointer myValue, it will be type-safe at this point anyways (which is something I want) so the cast is basically pointless.

Let me just add that I'm sure people will point out: Why don't you just return (NSNumber*) from the getValue method but in my case I want to have the flexibility to return whatever I want much like the built in NSDictionary class returns id when you call: objectForKey because it allows you to place any type of NSObject or subclass inside of it. In other words my getValue method will not always be returning an NSNumber.  Also consider this example is contrived because I am just concerned about whether to cast or not.

Thank you in advance,

-Ralph

Comment: See also: [Using dot notation for instance methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6364555/557219)

Comment: Note that you shouldn't have a `getValue` method;  it should just be `value`.  `get` as a prefix means something very specific in Cocoa;  that some of the arguments will be return-by-reference.

Comment: Thank you bbum and Josh Caswell for pointing out the recommendation to avoid methods with a get prefix.  I'll definitely be rewriting a couple of my methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason to cast objects is to make the compiler happy. (Sometimes it also helps readability.) For example, you have to cast when making a property access directly on an object you're getting out of an array or dictionary:

```
((Foo *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0]).bar;
```

If you don't do the cast, the compiler can't do the property lookup, and will complain.

When you're getting an object from a method that returns `id`, it's impossible for the compiler to know what its actual type is. There isn't really any "type-safety", because `id` is a generic pointer; all the compiler can and will enforce is that the method says it returns some Objective-C object. It is perfectly happy to assign a generic pointer to any typed pointer.* (This is actually an advantage for containers, obviously.) Since the type of the variable to which you're assigning already documents the *actual* return type, I'd say there's no need for the cast.

As an aside, you shouldn't be calling your method `getX`. That has a specific meaning in Cocoa; methods which "get" something pass in a pointer to a pointer, which is then filled by the method. See [`-[NSArray getObjects:range:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBGGHJ) as an example.

---

*The type will be enforced at run-time, of course, in the sense that sending messages to which the object does not respond will cause an error.