# Accessing getters using dot notation in Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've recently discovered that there is no need to declare a getter as a property to use the dot notation. I don't know about other compiler versions, but this is true for Apple LLVM 3.1. Does anyone foresees any problems with it? So, basically:

```
 ---------Star.h----------  
 -(UInt32)age;

 ---------Star.m----------
 -(UInt32)age
 {
    //get star age
    return starAge;   
 }


 ---------RootViewController.m----------
 {
 ...
 //use this instead of [star age] even if there is no synthesized property "age" 
 NSLog(@"%i", star.age);

 ...

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using dot notation for instance methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364555/using-dot-notation-for-instance-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly acceptable. A compiler wold do something similiar if you wrote:

```
 ---------Star.h----------  
@property (readonly) UInt32 age;


 ---------Star.m----------
@synthesize age = starAge;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Dot notation is just another way to invoke an instance method.

`self.foo = bar;` is the same as `[self setFoo:bar];`
`bar = self.foo;` is the same as `bar = [self foo];`

Comment: Actually, it seems that you can't use the dot notation only by having a setter methods, you need to declare a property in order to do that.

Comment: calling a setter without property by dot notation works for me without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

What does ARC make of that?

What happens if you try to compile :

```
- (void)setX:(NSInteger)x {
    NSLog(@"New x is %i", x);
}

...

[self setX:100];
```

without declaring X as a property?

Comment: Isn't his question for a readOnly property held in iVar starAge?

Comment: In his example, yes. However, he might try to extend this patten for other things. I'd quite like the question on stack overflow to consider that (even if I'm wrong!)

Comment: There is a problem with that, you can't use the dot notation for a setter if you don't declare a property. Please correct me if I'm wrong, my test suggest this, but not entirely sure.

Comment: Ofcourse. This property could only be 'set' trough iVar starAge from the Star object itself (i'm talking about OP's code).

Comment: @ValentinRadu You're absolutely correct :) Getters will work without a property, setters won't.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it works I feel that it's good practice to add that simple extra line of code to declare it as a property even if all it does is make your code more readable.